# convert NSDictionary value to NSInteger

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsnumber

i have an NSDictionary that contain in value and i need to get this value 
i have tried to get the value using the following code:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01  
                         target:self
                               selector:@selector(timerMovelabel:) 
                               userInfo:
            [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:var forKey:@"var1"]
     , [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:23] forKey:@"var2"]
```

i have tried to get the value using the following methods

1. `int intvar = [[[timer userInfo] objectForKey:@"var2"] intValue];`
2. `NSNumber *numbervar = [[timer userInfo] objectForKey:@"var2"];
      NSInteger intvar = [num intValue];`
3. Follows:

   ```
   [self method:[[[timer userInfo] objectForKey:@"var2"] intValue]];


   - (void)timerMovelabel:(NSTimer *)timer {
       //here i execute one of the steps 1,2 and 3 but i didn't get any result all values are null
   }


   - (void) method:(NSInteger)dir 
   { 
        NSLog(@"%d",dir);
   }
   ```

Comment: Please format use code using the provided editor tools, otherwise it makes it very hard to read.

Comment: Please describe where this does not behave as you expect and whatever warnings or errors you see. It looks like you are trying to pass a comma separated list of dictionaries as your `userInfo` argument and that doesn't make any sense. Show us the code you are actually using not just select lines out of context.

Comment: You’re missing the `repeats` parameter in that `NSTimer` class method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup of the timer appears to be wrong. You can not pass more than one dictionary to the userInfo parameter.

Try:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(timerMovelabel:)
                               userInfo:
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: var, @"var1", 
                                                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:23], @"var2",
                                                     nil]
                               repeats:NO];
```

EDIT: Added repeats parameter, thanks Bavarious.

Comment: You’re missing the `repeats` parameter in that `NSTimer` class method.

Comment: nice work BVC. thx a lot. but i have 1 question what is the gaol for using the repeats parameter?? what is the difference between repeats:YES and repeats:NO??

Comment: If repeats is NO, the timer invalidates automatically when it first fires, otherwise it will repeat with the given time interval.

Answer (score 1):

Your userInfo is not built correctly. You need to pass only one object in there.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01  
                         target:self
                               selector:@selector(timerMovelabel:) 
                               userInfo:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:23] forKey:@"var2"]
      repeats:NO];
```

EDIT: If you would like to pass a dictionary with multiple keys and values, then you can do it with dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys: .

Moszi

Comment: His original code specifies two objects in the dictionary, not one only. Also, there’s no reason to use `NSMutableDictionary` unless `timerMovelabel:` changes the the dictionary.

Comment: Agree with NSMutableDictionary. Updated. And added note for dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys: .